Automatically calculating distance on specific layer in QGIS
In the photo above, I have an area that is drawn. This is my case study.
I'd like to calculate the distance of the electrical networks, according to their voltage, inside my case study.
I know how to do an automatic distance calculation, but here, if I do it, it will calculate the distance of all the electrical networks in the world because it's its boundary.
In my case, I only want the networks inside my case study but I don't know how to get QGIS to take them into account because a simple filter won't work (my case study covers several countries).
Is there a function that automatically calculates all the electrical networks on my layer?
I use the "power_line" layer on OpenInfraMap: https://openinframap.org/map.json


Distance from what to what? And what do you mean by "automatically"? Upon feature creation? Upon loading the layer into QGIS?

I want to do it like this: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/calculating_line_lengths.html but I have a grid (in purple) and I just want the length in my layer. The problem here is that the grid layer is for the world...

So you clip & then calculate the length?

Yes ! But just in my layer...

I don't get what you want to tell me with that comment.

Have you the data saved to a format such as geopackage?

In the photo above, I have drawn a zone that represents my case study. I would like to calculate the distance of the electrical networks present within this zone. I know how to automatically calculate the distance, but in this case, if I do it, it will calculate the distance of all the electrical networks present worldwide because that is its default delimitation.
In my case, I only want the networks within my case study area, but I don't know how to take this into account in QGIS, as a simple filter wouldn't work (my case study is spread across several countries).

No @Aquamarine
You need to "add a vector tile layer" on QGIS, by entering the following link: https://openinframap.org/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf
Then go to symbology, and remove all the layers.
Then add a line and write: power_line in the layer name.

I think you need to have the data in a format such as geopackage/postgis/shapefile etc,  to use vector tools such as clip (to calculate within your zone of interest) and Add Geometry Attributes - to calculate the length of powerlines - those tools can not take a vector tile layer as input

The data in openinframap is from the OSM database - so you could get the data directly from OSM - power=line

You could use the plugin QuickOSM to get the data

Sorry, I don't know how i can do

Instructions posted

First download the data using Quick OSM:

Result should be something like this:

Then use the geo-processing tool Clip with the osm layer as input and the zone of interest layer as the overlay - this should give you something like this:

Then export to a geopackage.  Check data for any inconsistencies in the field voltage - as it is a text field you may have other data such as a range in there, instead of just an integer value.  And there will be many features with NULL in the field instead of a voltage value.
The simplest way to get lengths is to first run Dissolve using field Voltage as the "Dissolve" field.

Next set the project CRS to a CRS suitable for the area (if the data is in the default CRS) and then run Add Geometry Attributes:

The final result should be a layer where the number of features correspond to the number of unique values in the field voltage:

As this layer is an in-memory layer - save it to a format such as geopackage.
